# Putting two queries together

Tags: elasticsearch

How am I able to put both of these queries together, as you can see that query one is bringing back all the date from today and the second query is bringing back data for all users that has the name test in it.

So I want to bring back all of the data for data with the name that has test in it.
Could someone show me how this is done please?

Query one:

```
{  
   "_source":["VT"],
 "query": {
        "range": {
            "VT": {
                "gte": "now/d",
                "lt": "now/d+13h"
            }
        }}

}
```

Query two:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT"],

                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
        {"wildcard": {"N": "TEST*"}}
      ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10

               )

for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
    print(doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `bool` query with two `must` clauses, like this:

```
{
  "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "VT"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "VT": {
              "gte": "now/d",
              "lt": "now/d+13h"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "N": "TEST*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Check out the docs for the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:
POST _search

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "VT": {
                        "gte": "now/d", 
                        "lt": "now/d+13h"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
            "match": {
              "N": {
                "query": "TEST",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```